# Existing unit test framework that will test NodeJs server side and client side?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, node.js

So there seems to have been a flurry of new Unit test frameworks that have popped up for Node since it was released. https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#wiki-testing

Can't I use an existing framework to test my client and NodeJs server side JavaScript code? I don't want to have to go and learn yet ANOTHER implementation.

Answer (score 2):

[nodeunit](https://github.com/caolan/nodeunit) is a solid unit testing library that works both on server and client.

It uses a very simply assertion API and feels familiar to Qunit.

However TJHolowaychuck recently released [mocha](https://github.com/visionmedia/mocha) which sounds like a solid alternative. I'd recommend placing bets on this library merely because TJ is a rock solid module author.

Answer (score 1):

We've been using [Jasmine](http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/) which works both as a Node module and also as a browser based test runner for client side Javascript. Its very mature, very easy to get started with and very well respected.